# run headless chrome on lambda

Tags: lambda, chromium, google-chrome-headless, lighthouse

I would like to run lighthouse (5.1) tests using AWS Lamda, on top of headless chrome or chromium, but aws lambda seems to be limited to 250mb (including layers)

I found this project, but it seems to have not updated chromium binaries:
https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome

and it's docker build didn't work for me (threw an error)

it's latest version, didn't work with node 10, which is a requirement of lighthouse 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) which is optimised for use in Lambda.